Geographic transformation issue
I have a point feature class in GDA94 Zone 54. I want the coordinates for each point in GDA94 Zone 54, but also want them in GDA2020 Zone 54. My ArcGIS project is in GDA94 Zone 55. When using Calculate Geometry to get the coordinates in 2020 they are different from if I reproject the dataset into GDA2020 then calculate them. I assume the latter results are correct, but thought the Calculate Geometry tool would be able to do GDA94 and 2020 without needing to reproject the feature class since you choose what coordinate system you want calculated? Is the project's CRS impacting this?

Check that the display map (are you using Pro or ArcMap?) is using the same GDA94/GDA2020 transformation that the Project tool is using. Also, make sure that the ArcGIS Coordinate Systems Data setup is installed.
